# Issues reading variable from .dat file in C

Tags: c, file, structure

In the program I have to make for an assignment we are given a .dat file, which has data in the format: ID number[9+1 character], last name[50+1], name[50+1], date of birth[3 integers], street[100+1 character], street number[integer], city[30+1 character].

From that .dat file I'm supposed to create a structure with all the data. My problem is that the ID number is read incorrectly, while the rest of it is read correctly. Plus, the ID number changes each time I compile the code.

I've tried reading the file from a separate function and from main, and I compared my code to the sample code our proffessor gave us, but I can't find an error. I also tried changing the ID type to integer, but the error persists.

The structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char oib[9 + 1];
    char prezime[50 + 1];
    char ime[50 + 1];
    int dan;
    int mj;
    int god;
    char ulica[100 + 1];
    int ulbroj;
    char grad[30 + 1];
} Puk;
```

Function for reading from .dat file:

```
Puk* readPuk(int* n) {
    FILE* fin = fopen("puk.dat", "rb");

    fseek(fin, 0, SEEK_END);
    int br = ftell(fin) / sizeof(Puk);
    rewind(fin);

    Puk* rez = (Puk*)malloc(sizeof(Puk) * br);
    fread(&rez[0], sizeof(Puk), br, fin);

    *n = br;
    fclose(fin);
    return rez;
}
```

The bit for outputting the data read:

```
Puk* pukBin = readPuk(&nPuk);

for (i = 0; i < nPuk; i++) {
    fprintf(fout, "-----------\n");
    fprintf(fout, "OIB: %d\nPrezime: %s\nIme:%s\nDatum:%d.%d.%d\nUlica:%s\nBroj:%d\nGrad:%s\n", pukBin[i].oib, pukBin[i].prezime, pukBin[i].ime, pukBin[i].dan, pukBin[i].mj, pukBin[i].god, pukBin[i].ulica, pukBin[i].ulbroj, pukBin[i].grad);
}
```

Comment: `OIB: %d`. Are you sure the id is stored as an `int`? The structure implies it is actually stored as a string. Perhaps try `%s` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @kaylum Wow. I've been looking at my code for hours at this point. That was the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was using a `%d` when outputting to a .txt file, instead of using a `%s`.